# AS3 - error 1120: Access of undefined property stage

Tags: actionscript-3, stage

I'm trying to add the QuickKong class to a game I'm making, as described here: http://www.kongregate.com/forums/90-kongregate-apis/topics/199155-quickkong-easy-kong-api-integration

To call the class, you use:

```
QuickKong.connectToKong(stage);
```

However, it keeps giving me:

```
error 1120: Access of undefined property stage.
```

Any suggestions?  Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The stage is a property of a `DisplayObject`. When a `DisplayObject` is not on the `Stage` its stage property is `undefined`.

So, you need to make sure the stage is available when you run `QuickKong.connectToKong(stage);`.

If you do this in the constructor of your document class it should work just fine. Chances are you're trying to do this in some other class that doesn't have a stage property.

If the class you're trying to run this in extends a `DisplayObject` such as `MovieClip` or `Sprite` you can listen for when it is added to the stage and then run your `QuickKong` code. Like this:

```
package  {

import flash.display.MovieClip;
import flash.events.Event;

public class Test extends MovieClip {


    public function Test() {
        addEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, onAdded);
    }

    private function onAdded(e:Event):void{
        // now the stage is available
        QuickKong.connectToKong(stage);
    }
}
```

}

Now, if for some reason you are not running your `QuickKong` code in a class that has access to the stage you should pass a reference to the stage into that class's constructor, like this:

```
var someClass:SomeClass = new SomeClass(stage);
```

Lastly, in your document class you could make a static variable reference the stage. Like this:

```
package  {

import flash.display.MovieClip;

public class Main extends MovieClip {


    public function Main() {
        Main.stage = stage;
    }

}
```

}

Now, you can just say: `Main.stage` anywhere in your code when you need to talk about the stage:

```
QuickKong.connectToKong(Main.stage);
```